# GAN Generator output layer is [way] out of target range - potentially due to loss func

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano

The TL;DR is that my G(z) (z is normal distributed noise) is way out of the expected range. [Picture - see comparison of real against generated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR6cg.jpg).
(It's also a terrible model, being just a few dense layers - but I can sort that later!)

I've thrown s**t at the wall for the past week to see what sticks and now it's time to ask for an informed opinion! :)

1. Has anyone else encountered this problem before? Suggested fixes?
2. What is your generic loss function for your regressive Generator (with a categorical discriminator)?

As it's a regression problem (with target data normalised between 0 & 1) my G output has a `linear` activation. However, I'm trying to follow [Soumith's GAN Hacks](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks) to get it working, where we're conflicting over the activation - he says it should be `tanh`. One could assume with my expected target range I could choose `sigmoid`, but as I say, I infer this should be `linear` as a regressive problem to solve. Opinions?

Plus there isn't much clarity on the loss function. He Says:-

> In GAN papers, the loss function to optimize G is `min (log 1-D)`, but in practice folks practically use `max log D`

Does this mean one should aim to minimise the error `log(1-D)`, or pick the minimum of `log(1-D)`? Similarly  with max `log(D)`. (I'm using class definitions of true/false, so a maximum and minimum from the can be chosen from the two classes.)

In the [Goodfellow et. al  2014 paper on GANs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf), I can see how some of the loss function for the Discriminator resolves to 0 when applied to the Generator. However, I'm obviously missing something, as the equation states I should take `log(D(x))` which will sooner or later hit a NaN.

Clarification about my confused state is thanked many times in advance.

---

Update:

[This tutorial on O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/generative-adversarial-networks-for-beginners) says

> Take a look at the last line of our discriminator: there's no softmax or sigmoid layer at the end. GANs can fail if their discriminators "saturate," or become confident enough to return exactly 0 when they're given a generated image; that leaves the discriminator without a useful gradient to descend.

Which sounds a little like my problem, especially as I was using `Softmax`. Using no activation doesn't solve the problem, but does make my GAN compete in interesting new ways!

Comment: Just giving my 2 cents: I am using https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan. For the loss part, generator is just trying to minimize `min log (1-D)` which means the generator hopes to generate images that the discriminator will think they are true images.

Comment: "I can see how some of the loss function for the Discriminator resolves to 0 when applied to the Generator" this looks fishy to me. Image that we are in situation that generator can generate perfect images. Then the discriminator cannot distinguish between real and generated images. So discriminator just randomly guesses. The loss function at this point is not zero.

Comment: May be this question is more suited to Cross Validated.SE.

Comment: Thanks @LKS, I'll see if I can implement those resources and get back to you with an update.
As far as the maths goes, the discriminator loss that has the `log D(x)` part isn't seen in the generator as `log D(x)` is always true (ie; 1) when swapping labels to use gradient ascent: `log(1)=0`. Although, when false (ie; 0) this would surely be NaN?

Comment: @Kanmani, Cross-Validated Squared Error? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Kanmani means https://stats.stackexchange.com/